Angular propagating two-way updates between child and parent components
I have a parent component that is passing an input model to a child component:
Parent:
chart = signal<AnyChart | null>(null);
 <app-style-panel
      [(chart)]="chart"
    ></app-style-panel>

Child:
chart = model.required<AnyChart | null>();
I'm using model instead of input because I want the child to write new values to the signal.
In the child I also have a form:
  private fb = inject(FormBuilder);

  chartForm = this.fb.nonNullable.group({
    title: ['', [Validators.required]],
    description: [''],
    xlabel: [''],
    ylabel: [''],
    ysuffix: [''],
  });

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.chartForm.valueChanges
      .pipe(debounceTime(300), takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef))
      .subscribe((v) => {
        // update the chart model signal here
      });
  }

  constructor() {
    effect(() => {
      if (this.chart()) {
        this.chartForm.setValue({
          title: this.chart()!.title,
          description: this.chart()!.description,
          xlabel: this.chart()!.xlabel,
          ylabel: this.chart()!.ylabel,
          ysuffix: this.chart()!.ysuffix,
        });
      }
    });
  }


How to update the chart with new values coming from the form? The issue is I have an effect() that updates the chartForm values based on changes in the chart model signal. So we end up with two things trying to update each other. What is the best way to handle this??
